# Инкремент при вставке записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Каким образом реализовывается инкремент?

К примеру,

```
SET инкремент=1;
INSERT INTO ТЕСТ('ДОМ_1', 'ДОМ_2')
VALUES (инкремент++(инкремент=1),инкремент++(инкремент=2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, можно поступить следующим образом

```
SET @inc = 1;
INSERT INTO ТЕСТ('ДОМ_1', 'ДОМ_2')
VALUES (@inc := @inc + 1, @inc := @inc + 1);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное за мгновенный ответ. однако принять могу только через 8 минут)